# How to Merge Two Google Script in One - Google SpreadSheet Insert Time depend of the column modify

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this two script if the same structure, the only different is the following:

> Create Date: Insert Date only if the column 1 (A) is modified. 
>   Last Update: Insert Date only if somone modify Column 5 or 6.

I think is simple adding some else or null but I don't have the expertice to do it... If anyone can help I will appreciate soo much.

## SCRIPT 1:

```
function CreationDate(event){
  //Script Creation Date Timming

  var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detec the ActiveCell

  var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the Column of the ActiveCell
  var colNums  = [1]; //Coulmns, whose edit is considered
  if(colNums.indexOf(column) == -1) return; //If column other than considered then return

  var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the ActiveRow
  if(row < 2)   return; //If header row then return

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format

  var r1 = event.source.getActiveRange().getRow();

  //Note: Insert the Date in Create Date Column
  actSht.getRange(r1, 7).setValue(date)
}
```

## SCRIPT 2:

```
function LastUpdate(e){
//Script LastUpdate Timming

  var actSht = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detec the ActiveCell

  var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the Column of the ActiveCell
  var colNums  = [5,6]; //Coulmns, whose edit is considered
  if(colNums.indexOf(column) == -1) return; //If column other than considered then return

  var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the ActiveRow
  if(row < 2)   return; //If header row then return

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format

  var r2 = e.source.getActiveRange().getRow();
  //Note: Insert the Date in the Column 8
  actSht.getRange(r2, 8).setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two functions are exactly the same with two exceptions:

1. The first initializes the array colNums with one element, the second with two (ninth line).
2. They output values to different columns (last line, 7 vs. 8).

A single function could easily do both:

```
function setTimeStamp(e){
    // no magic numbers!
    var createdColNums  = [1]; //Columns whose edit is considered a new row
    var updatedColNums  = [5,6]; //Columns whose edit is considered an updated row
    var createdStampColumn = 7;
    var updatedStampColumn = 8;
    var headerRow = 1;

    var actSht = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detect the ActiveCell
    var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the active row
    if(row == headerRow)   
        return; //If header row then return

    var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the active column
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    var columnToStamp;

    if(createdColNums.indexOf(column) > -1) 
        columnToStamp = createdStampColumn;
    else if(updatedColNums.indexOf(column) > -1) 
        columnToStamp = updatedStampColumn;

    actSht.getRange(row, columnToStamp).setValue(date);
}
```

Note: if you name the function onEdit() and place it in a spreadsheet's script, it will automatically be called as a trigger, and it will not need to be authorized.  In that case use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
```

in place of

```
e.source.getActiveSheet()
```

All that said, imho a better methodology would be to check for a value where the created time stamp goes, and if a value exists set the updated time stamp instead.  Then you'd get correct output any time any column was edited:

```
function onEdit() {
    // no magic numbers!
    var createdStampColumn = 7;
    var updatedStampColumn = 8;
    var headerRow = 1;

    var actSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detect the ActiveCell
    var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the active row
    if(row == headerRow)   
        return; //If header row then return

    var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the active column
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    var columnToStamp;

    if (actSht.getRange(row, createdStampColumn).getValue() == "")
        columnToStamp = createdStampColumn;
    else
        columnToStamp = updatedStampColumn;

    actSht.getRange(row, columnToStamp).setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without paying a real attention to what your script is actually doing, here is a "literal translation/combination" of both scripts. Note that I inverted the conditions to avoid "returning" from the script and so be able to go to the second condition.

```
function combined_function(event){
  var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detec the ActiveCell
  var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the Column of the ActiveCell
  var colNums  = [1]; //Coulmns, whose edit is considered
  if(colNums.indexOf(column) > -1) { //If column is the one we want then execute
    var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the ActiveRow
    if(row >= 2){
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format
      var r1 = event.source.getActiveRange().getRow();
      //Note: Insert the Date in Create Date Column
      actSht.getRange(r1, 7).setValue(date)
    }
  };// end of first original function
  colNums  = [5,6]; //Coulmns, whose edit is considered
  if(colNums.indexOf(column) > -1){ // same comment, condition inverted
    var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the ActiveRow
    if(row >= 2){
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format
      var r2 = e.source.getActiveRange().getRow();
      //Note: Insert the Date in the Column 8
      actSht.getRange(r2, 8).setValue(date);
    }
  }
}
```